# getServiceLocator() not working in module.php

Tags: zend-framework2

i m doing authentication using Zend Framework2 MongoDB ODM Authentication, i have to pass the object of Authentication to the session variable in Module.php to make a session, but i m getting error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /mnt/hgfs/directory/module/Admin/Module.php" this is because the Module file does not know the Service Manager. how to inject Service Manager in Module.php?

Comment: Considering all your latest question just one advice: Learn the Framework before trying to build rich applications. The official documentation is not as bad anymore as the rumors make them to be, so work yourself through them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private $app;
private $serviceManager;
....
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $this->app = $e->getApplication();
    $this->serviceManager = $this->app->getServiceManager();
    ....
}
```

Within your Module class get a MvcEvent parameter and get the event. Within the bootstrap get the application and you should have access to your Service manager within your bootstrap.